# Projector tab is blank in PyTorch Tensorboard

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

I'm trying to visualize embeddings per epoch. But the Projector page shows this -

[image: screenshot of problem]

Here's the text from the page -

```
No checkpoint was found.

Probable causes:

    No checkpoint has been saved yet. Please refresh the page periodically.
    You are not saving any checkpoint. To save your model, create a tf.train.Saver and save your model periodically by calling saver.save(session, LOG_DIR/model.ckpt, step).

If you’re new to using TensorBoard, and want to find out how to add data and set up your event files, check out the README and perhaps the TensorBoard tutorial.

If you think TensorBoard is configured properly, please see the section of the README devoted to missing data problems and consider filing an issue on GitHub.
```

To simplify things, I use the following to generate an embedding inside my training loop; still did not work.

```
for e in epochs:
    .
    .
    writer.add_embedding(torch.randn(100, 5), global_step=e)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried restarting TensorBoard? Do you get any error on your browser's console?

Comment: Yes, I've tried restarting the console. Even deleted the `./runs` directory. I've updated the question with the screenshot of browser console. Please check it out. For reference, Graphs/Scalar/Histogram/Images all work. Only embedding does not.

Answer (score 0):

After running into the same error I tried running a sample script for embeddings and suddenly it worked.

I narrowed it down to: adding any image to Tensorboard before or after adding an embedding makes it work. Like so:

`writer.add_image('image', np.ones((3,3,3)), 0)`

Not sure what is causing this.

Comment: I tried this out. Didn't work, unfortunately, for me.

Comment: `import torch;
import numpy as np;
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter;
import tensorboard;
import tensorflow;
tensorflow.io.gfile = tensorboard.compat.tensorflow_stub.io.gfile;
writer = SummaryWriter();
writer.add_image('image', np.ones((3,3,3)), 0);
writer.add_embedding(torch.randn(100, 5), global_step=0)`
Try running this MWE and selecting projector after restarting your tensorboard

Comment: The above solution by Atnas worked for me (in Google Colab)